# Magento2 doesn't load images and css

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, 404

I have downloaded and installed Magento 2 but I'm getting 404 error for scripts and css. An example of my image path is: http://www.arredomobilionline.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/it_IT/images/logo.svg

I've already tried this solution:

> Open up app/etc/di.xml and find the virtualType
>   name="developerMaterialization" section. In that section you'll find
>   an item name="view_preprocessed" that needs to be modified or deleted.
>   You can modify it by changing the contents from
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

inside my deafult di.xml file as default there's:

```
    <virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I tried to delete the first symlink part or change it into "copy" but it's not working.

Comment: What mode are you operating in? Default, developer or production? And did you run the static-deploy tool?

Comment: I think default, I downloaded magento 2 from the Magento website and I didn't change settings. As for the static-deploy tool I'm trying to understand how it works

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem that css was not loading and admin give 404 so that  Please check that mod_rewrite module is enable in server.

Comment: I've checked my htaccess and there's:     Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arredomobilionline\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.arredomobilionline.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2):

1. Change `"Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink"` to `"Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy"` in `app/etc/di.xml` file (line 598)
2. Run via ssh: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. Next command: `chmod -R 777 pub/*`
4. And finally: `rm -rf var/*`

This steps works fine for me ; )

Comment: Can changing this <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item> bring any performance problems as our site is running very slow?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This command works for me

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

You should setup the permissions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html

Comment: I've set 777 permission to every file

Answer (score 1):

give full permission for pub/static folder and run below php script

```
php D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2ee\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

(mention path is my local system and i run the script after going to php folder )

Comment: is it working fine in local setup??

Answer (score 0):

First, Check if the CSS and JS files have proper permissions. 
Then clear var/cache, var/page_cache and var/generation folders.

The try to run this command: magento setup:static-content:deploy - more details on this command are available here- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Now run your frontend URL. JS and CSS files should start coming now.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

add "Copy" instead of "copy" it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the store of a client. The problem was that Apache isn't following symlinks on this hosting environment. It returns 403 forbidden for symlinked static content files.

A **workaround solution** was to switch to production mode.

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`